# Form for getting routes to wrong controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

I have this form:

```
  <%= form_for @account, :as => :account, :url => current_account_path, :html => { :class => 'block' } do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>

    <%= f.submit 'Update', :class => 'button' %>
  <% end %>
```

which is being loaded from users#edit

However, I want it to submit to accounts#update. But, no matter what I do it always submits to users#update. Am I not specifying it correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're specifying the URL you want to submit to with the `:url` key in your hash: if that isn't the correct route, you should specify it there. So run `rake routes`, find the right URL in that list, and then put the correct path helper in there and it should work.

Comment: tried that. tried everything. I've tried setting the path, tried setting the controller/action combo, nothing helps. each time it always goes to the users#update action

Comment: Is the form nested inside another form? Because that's illegal HTML; the outer form will be the only one submitted. Try editing your post to include the result of `rake routes` and the entire view file.